# Почему в тюрьме — сидят?

Tags: лексика

Может быть, глупый вопрос, но подумалось: а почему в тюрьме именно сидят? Не стоят, не лежат, не находятся, а сидят?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такое значение у глагола "сидеть" - "находиться в каком-либо месте", видимо, связано с тем, что в ограниченном пространстве невозможно свободно перемещаться-ходить, бегать, а лежать в тюрьме  не дают, только в положенное время, и ходить на прогулку - в положенное время, а большую часть времени сидят в прямом смысле слова. Вот пироги в печи тоже сидят, то есть находятся, зверь сидит в клетке(хоть он там и лежит)."3 суток сижу на станции " - не означает в прямом смысле сидеть, можно и ходить, и лежать, а говорим "сижу", то есть ограничен в свободном движении, нахожусь в замкнутом пространстве.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что на начальной стадии существования исправительной системы наказания тюрьмы представляли собой яму в земле, в которой заключенный не мог встать в полный рост. Высота ямы была такой, что заключенный мог только сидеть в ней, в прямом смысле. Вот поэтому и говорят: "сидеть в тюрьме", а не лежать, стоять или прыгать.

Comment: Откатил на авторский вариант - с правкой правописания. Я приветствую правку орфографии, но нарушение авторского стиля и мысли - никогда.

Comment: На самом деле версия весьма экзотическая и скорее всего с истиной ничего общего не имеет ни в этимологическом, ни в историческом смысле. Правильный ответ - у Людмилы. Можно кое-что добавить или поправить, но суть там изложена верно.